# What is and How is length of a 2D,3D array calucated?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am slightly confused with concept... When printed a length of a 2D array of[20][20]. Answer was 120... But unable to figure out... How was it Calculated?

Comment: I don't know, how *was* it calculated? Mind sharing the code?

Comment: Just used the in-built .lenght function.... the answer was 120... was trying to figure out,"Why was it printed 120 and not 20."

Comment: It wouldn't be, if you *really* had constructed it with [20][20]. I suspect this is a diagnostic problem. See my answer for an example of it printing 20. If you can provide a similar short but complete program printing 120 unexpectedly, please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of a 2D array of [20][20] is actually just 20... because a 2D array is just an array of arrays. The "outer" array is an array of length 20, each element of which is an array of length 20.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] array = new int[20][20];
        System.out.println(array.length); // Prints 20
    }
}
```

If you want to find the *total* number of elements of a multi-dimensional array, you'll need to sum the lengths of each subarray. For example:

```
public int findTotalLength(int[][] array)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int[] subArray : array)
    {
        sum += subArray.length;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that you can't just take the first sub-array's length and multiply the "outer" length by that, as other sub-arrays can have different lengths. (There could also be null references, which the above code doesn't try to detect.)

Answer (score -1):

len = rows * columns  (for a 2D array)
you can guess for 3D
2D  array to  just a programmers concept , all data in memory is stored in a serial manner